# how to get minimum and maximum date from given month in java

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

how to get minimum and maximum date from given month in java using java.util.Calendar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minimum is always the 1st of this month. The maximum can be determined by adding 1 to month and subtracting 1 from the Calendar day field.

Comment: thanks for the help, i got the solution as,
    public void ddl_month_valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        int v_month = Integer.parseInt(event.getNewValue().toString()) - 1;
        java.util.Calendar c1 = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.set(2011, v_month, 1);
        Date d_set_att_from = c1.getTime();
        cal_att_from_date.setValue(d_set_att_from);
        c1.add(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        c1.add(java.util.Calendar.DATE, -1);
        Date d_set_att_to = c1.getTime();
        cal_att_to_date.setValue(d_set_att_to);
    }

Comment: in which cal_att_from_date and cal_att_to_date is the object of org.primefaces.component.calendar.Calendar

Comment: @Annu, is this solution easier than just call one method?

Answer (score 3):

This could be done this way:

```
c = ... // get calendar for month you're interested in     
int numberOfDays = c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

You could find minimum and maximum value the same way for any of components of the date.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

After setting your calendar object to your desired month, 
calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);

For the minimum, I suppose it's always the first.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum date is always 1
and Maximum date can be calculate as

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year = 2010;
        int month = Calendar.FEBRUARY;
        int date = 1;
        int maxDay =0;  

        calendar.set(year, month, date);
        System.out.println("First Day: " + formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));

        //Getting Maximum day for Given Month
        maxDay = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        calendar.set(year, month, maxDay);  
        System.out.println("Last Day: " + formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Hopefully this will helps

Answer (score 0):

I got solution as below,

```
public void ddl_month_valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
 int v_month = Integer.parseInt(event.getNewValue().toString()) - 1; 
 java.util.Calendar c1 = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(); 
 c1.set(2011, v_month, 1); 
 Date d_set_att_from = c1.getTime(); 
 cal_att_from_date.setValue(d_set_att_from);
 c1.add(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, 1);
 c1.add(java.util.Calendar.DATE, -1); 
 Date d_set_att_to = c1.getTime();
 cal_att_to_date.setValue(d_set_att_to);  }
```